# Blockquote is Not responsive on Mobile

Tags: html, css

My quotes on slider images are not responsive on mobile. Can someone help me with what I need to add to css?
[CSS attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1nG67.png) 
[Mobile Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SmfTU.jpg)

```css
#home-hero blockquote {
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
  max-width: 400px;
  padding: 20px 0;
  border-top: 1px solid rgba(198, 167, 113, 0.5);
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(198, 167, 113, 0.5);
  text-align: center;
}

#home-hero blockquote p {
  font-family: 'Playfair Display', sans-serif;
  color: #99783d;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 200%;
  text-align: center;
  width: 120%;
  margin: 0 -10% 30px;
}

#home-hero blockquote cite {
  font-family: 'Playfair Display', sans-serif;
  color: #99783d;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 100%;
  font-style: italic;
}
```

```html
<div class="slide">
  <div class="quote">
    <blockquote>
      <p>Absolutely phenomenal custom home construction and attention to detail. Everyone who visits is "wowed”.</p>
      <cite>- Jerry and Deb Smith</cite>
    </blockquote>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Elizabeth, please edit your question and include a [mcve] so that we can reproduce the issue

Comment: Updated with current CSS

Comment: add a `word-wrap: break-word;` that should fix it, add it to the `p` tag

Comment: in the html? or css?

Comment: add `box-sizing:border-box;` to `#home-hero blockquote`.. maybe it will help you....

Comment: in the css code

Comment: What if I changed the ccs blockquote of max-width: 400px to a % instead of the px? @Ainz-sama

Comment: well im not sure if that would work, else if it doesnt you could try using a % `width` like `width: 40%`